# Using lagged dependent variables in machine learning regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, random-forest, ardl

I'm building a machine learning (random forest) regression model to predict flow in a river, using rainfall, relative humidity, air temperature and certain other climatic variables. Since flow on a particular day (`flow_t`) is highly correlated with flow on previous day (`flow_t_1`), I want to include lagged flow in the model formulation.

In case I build the model this way:

```
require(randomForest)
flow.rf=randomForest(flow_t~flow_t_1+temp+humidity..........)
```

How can I use the above model for predictions? 
Since the input dataset for prediction will not have the flow variable, I cannot include its lagged version in the prediction call. I know that the `dynlm` package can be used to perform 'autoregressive distributed lag modeling' to include lagged dependent variables, but how can this be done for machine learning models? Or even for other statistical modeling techniques, like GLMs and GAMs?

Comment: Define a new variable equal to lagged flow and use it as an input. (Also trim the variables so that they have equal length.) Is there a problem with that?

Comment: @RichardHardy Since flow is the dependent variable, it will be predicted using the model. Therefore I cannot use the lagged flow when I call predict().

Comment: I still don't see a problem, it should work. But perhaps I am not aware of something, I have not used random forests before.

Comment: Are you aware that at time $t$ you know $y_t$ and you can legitimately use it for forecasting $y_{t+1}$? You can define $x_t:=y_{t-1}$ (lagged dependent variable) and use $x_t$ for predicting $y_t$. You can supply the $x_t$ as an input to a neural network or some other machine learning tool just as you can supply any other regressor. Your statement *the input dataset for prediction will not have the flow variable* seems unfounded if you consider *lagged* flow (not the *contemporaneous* flow that you are supposed to be predicting).

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to use "predict" function in R to do predictions on lagged dependent variable?

Comment: This seems to be a R programming question on how to use "predict" function in R for lagged dependent variables. I think it's best suited for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you do not have the flow variable, how can you know that it is highly correlated?
2. Related to the first point, how can you predict the flow if you do not have the variable at first ? You would need the flow variable to make your regression.
3. In the macroeconomic and finance literature, there are ways to include latent (non-observable) series using Vector Autoregression (VAR) and Maximum Likelihood estimation. I suggest you have a look at [Ang & Piazzesi](http://web.stanford.edu/~piazzesi/AP.pdf) (2003)  in which they explain how they can "recreate" the latent series which, in a VAR, is also a dependent variable.
4. Once you obtain the series for flow, you can add `flow_t-1` as an explanatory variable. To obtain the forecast one period ahead (at $t+1$), you simply fit the model using the data you have at time t. For more than 1 period ahead forecasts, you need slightly more complicated dynamics.

Comment: 1. I have the flow variable to build the model. But when I use predict(), I use modified independent variables (rainfall, humidity etc.), which means I cannot use the same flow I used to build the model to create lagged flow; 

4. 1 period ahead forecasts is what I'm looking for. Is there a way to do this using machine learning algorithms?

Comment: Just to see if I understood correctly. You have a model of the type:
$flow_t=\alpha+\rho flow_{t-1}+\beta rain+\epsilon_t$ , correct ?

Then, since you have the value of $flow_{t-1}$, you can obtain the value of $flow_t$ by fitting the above regression (in other words, you forget about $\epsilon$.

If the above is valid for time $t$, it is also valid for $t+1$. Write both formulas together and plug in the expression of $flow_t$ in the expression $flow_{t+1}=...$. You will obtain $\rho^2 flow_{t-1}$. Hence, you have forecasted $flow_{t+1}$ using only information up to time $t$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed analysis. Yes, I am able to build a regression like you explained. Also, I can obtain flow_t+1 using flow_t-1, if my independent variables (rain, humidity etc.) stay the same. But when I actually use the regression model, I will want to supply it modified independent variables, in order to understand how the flow time-series responds. So I will not have flow_t-1, since the entire flow time-series is now modified. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096787/adding-lagged-variables-to-an-lm-model) question that is very similar.

Comment: @user89073 can you give any hint about how to do this For more than 1 period ahead forecasts and the dynamics associated with it?

Comment: @MdAzimulHaque You simply have to iterate forward your model. Once you have $flow_{t+1}$, you can multiply it by $\rho$ in order to have $flow_{t+2}$

Comment: @user89073 Thank you for your replies. But I'm still confused as to the practical considerations of implementing this. The problem is that I will want to work with new data, and not the data which was used to build the model, when using the model. For example, I build the model using 10 years of daily time-series data, using the lagged flow and other independent predictors to predict flow. I will then try to predict flow for 2 years of new data. Therefore I don't have flow available as a predictor, since I'm trying to predict it.

Comment: @user89073 Continuing from previous comment: I'm trying to do something like what the 'dyn' package does, which allows to build models like "dyn$lm(y ~ lag(y, -1) + x)". But I don't understand how this package allows predictions to happen, since 'y' is unknown when predicting with new input data. Does this work by iterative 1-step ahead prediction?

Comment: @small_world I honestly have no idea as to how this package works. I suggest you read the documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to include another column of variable in your actual data set which contains the lagged values of the dependent. You can chop the current data that you have to training data and testing data. You use the training data to create a random forest model and adjust it depending on its performance on the testing data. If you have a satisfactory model you can then forecast the 2 years flow rate. Now, to forecast the flow rate, while using its lagged values, you'll need to do a recursive forecasting, predicting one day at a time and using the predicted value as your input in the next forecast. Hope this helps.